# Plugin installation failed in QGIS 3.28 in macOS Catalina

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to install any plugin (official ones) and I keep getting the following message:

> Plugin installation failed: Failed to unzip the plugin package.
> Probably it's broken or missing from the repository. You may also want
> to make sure that you have write permission to the plugin directory:
> /Users/user/Library/Application
> Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins.

I have write permission on such folder.

The same happens if I try to install a plugin through a zip file.
It also happens for Ubuntu users.

How can I fix the issue?